# c# Intermittent Json deserialize error getting cookie value?

Tags: c#-4.0, cookies, json.net, json-deserialization

### Problem: Occasional Error during Json deserialize

I am occasionally receiving the following JsonReaderException in my .cs file:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

on a line of code which loads in and deserializes a JSON formatted cookie object using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert **in this line of code:**

```
Dictionary<string, string> Z3Cookie = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(MyCookinator.Get("MyZ3"));
```

**The JSON value from cookie as per Firebug =**
{"a": "4dSlshoOCgkg0zQop1cdZx41llyTzLlli1Ol19fNCK14dSlsh21pluss8qh74dSlshpluss85KnbQeq22eq22", "b": "9999", "c": "11", "d": "0", "e": "4dSlshoOCgkg0zQop1cdZx41llyTzLlli1Ol19fNCK14dSlsh21pluss8qh74dSlshpluss85KnbQeq22eq22", "f": "/jtemplates/ratesn.html", "g": "1", "h": "1", "i": "0", "j": "0", "k": "0", "l": "0", "m": "0", "n": "0", "o": "0", "p": "0", "q": "0", "r": "0", "s": "0", "t": "0", "u": "0", "v": "0", "w": "0", "x": "0", "y": "0", "z": "0"}

The MyCookinator function getting the cookie value =

```
public static string Get(string cookieName)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    Verify.That(context != null, "HttpContext is not available.");

    var responseCookie = GetCookie(context.Response.Cookies, cookieName);
    if (responseCookie != null)
    {
        return responseCookie.Value;
    }

    var requestCookie = GetCookie(context.Request.Cookies, cookieName);
    if (requestCookie != null)
    {
        return requestCookie.Value;
    }
     return null;
}
```

**EDIT:** more info= the GetCookie function is:

```
private static HttpCookie GetCookie(HttpCookieCollection cookies, string key)
    {
        if (!cookies.AllKeys.Any(cookieKey => cookieKey == key))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return cookies[key];
    }
```

I am at a loss as to why I get an error only sometimes on this line, when the content structures of the cookie do not change.

### Help..

I use Newtonsoft.Json in various areas of the c# .Net 4.0 site code with no problems and am looking to find a solution to my problem using Newtonsoft's deserializer.   What am I missing ?

Comment: My testing has narrowed down the problem (I think) to the variable "f": "/jtemplates/ratesn.html" in the Json string from the server.

Comment: Are you (or is your client code) inadvertently URL-encoding the JSON string somewhere?  If so, that would cause a % character to appear at the start of the string and make the JSON invalid.